# Net::SSH.start Timeout connecting to Vagrant host in Ruby

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

I have a `vagrant` VM running.

```
vagrant init centos/7
```

Generates the minimal `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
end
```

`vagrant ssh-config` reports the following:

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile "/path/to/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key"
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

However, the following seems to fail:

```
require 'net/ssh'
Net::SSH.start("127.0.0.1", "vagrant", {
    :auth_methods => [
        "publickey",
        "password"
    ],
    :port=>"2222",
    :keys => [
        "/path/to/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key"
    ]
})
```

With the following:

```
Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:90:in `rescue in initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:57:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:233:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:233:in `start'
    from (irb):2
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I can connect using SSH, as expected:

```
ssh -p 2222 -i /path/to/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key vagrant@127.0.0.1
```

How can I connect to a `vagrant` host in Ruby on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but it deserves to be added to the thread in an effort to help ...

If had this exact problem with `Chef` and `Ruby` on a local machine with VBox so first know you aren't alone. It does not appear to be a problem with the underlying `Ruby` framework which you can test with:

Note you'll need to adjust IP & user

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/ssh'

puts "opening connection.\n"
new_connection = Net::SSH.start('192.168.1.116', 'root', {:keys => ['~/.ssh/id_rsa'], :keepalive => true, :keepalive_interval => 60, :timeout => 60}) 
puts "connection established, run uptime.\n"
puts new_connection.exec!('uptime')
puts "running uname -a\n"
puts new_connection.exec!('uname -a')
puts "sleeping for 300 seconds.\n"
(1..5).each do |iterator|
  sleep_seconds = iterator * 60
  sleep 60
  puts "#{sleep_seconds}\n"
end
puts "running uptime.\n"
puts new_connection.exec!('uptime')
puts "running uname -a\n"
puts new_connection.exec!('uname -a')
puts "closing connection.\n"
new_connection.close
puts "done.\n"
```

Then execute with: `ruby ./test.rb`

The `Chef` failure has a very similar output to your own and note the same versions:

```
DEBUG: establishing connection to chef-arch-node:22
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:90:in `rescue in initialize': Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout (Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout)
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:57:in `initialize'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:233:in `new'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:233:in `start'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/server.rb:186:in `new_session'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/session.rb:488:in `next_session'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/server.rb:138:in `session'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/session_actions.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in sessions'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/logging-2.2.2/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:474:in `block in create_with_logging_context'
```